# Jenkins pipeline is using 3.0.5 version of maven instead of 3.8.8

Tags: maven, jenkins, centos, sonarqube, pipeline

I am using CentOS 7 as my vm where I have installed maven 3.8.8 using wget.My maven home path is /home/Mohit/apache-maven-3.8.8
But when I am starting a pipeline project it is taking maven 3.0.5 as the maven version.How do I make it use the updated version ie 3.8.8 which i installed using wget

I tried to delete the 3.0.5 version wch I installed using yum.

Comment: First you should configure the tools you use in Jenkins via global tool configuration and also CentOS 7 not the best platform anymore because the support is running out for Jenkins also using Maven 3.8.8 is also a bit out of date... current version 3.9.5... (https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2023/07/10/jenkins-june-newsletter/#key-takeaways)